# Animation dose not render if i set armature copy location of Empty

Tags: rendering, animation

Animation dose not render if i set armature copy location of Empty
Empty is linked to Track track is tracking face[image]

Animation In 3d Viewport is working fine 
but if try to render movie there is no movement at all...just still frame.
I use Eevee . Same with Cycles.

[image: render settinds]

Comment: Is the modifier visible for render?

Comment: It's using modifiers in render. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I am having the same problem, I was wondering if you found anything about this:
I have a snowboarder, I added armature/IK and so on. It was easier for me to apply an empty with parent on the snowboard. Then, i added a copy loc constraint on this empty for one foot. The animation looks great, but when I rendered it, the copy loc constraint is not rendered.
If anybody can help with some advice i'd be grateful Thanks!